# How to test the purpose string of NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in iOS using Expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, appstore-approval

I've been struggling to verify if the purpose string for photo library access really is working as expected. It started with the application got rejected because it wasn't set.

Using expo-image-picker, it says in the docs that adding this into the plugins section in app.json should set the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription:

```
  [
    "expo-image-picker",
    {
      "photosPermission": "This allows you to upload a photo to your Appname profile."
    }
  ]
```

Before I added this, I basically added NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to the plist key inside ios section in app.json. What I can see, both do exactly the same thing.

After building ios using `expo build:ios` I was able to verify that that the string existed in the Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This allows you to upload a photo to your Appname profile.</string>
```

Using Expo Go doesn't really help since when requesting permissions, it says "Expo Go" in the alert.

Also, I only have experience working with Expo / React Native, and have no access to a mac (or xcode).

When apple test this, it looks like this (according to their screenshot):
[image]

While the expected text should be:
This allows you to upload a photo to your Appname profile.

**How can I verify that the purpose string is really set (and works) before submitting an application to App store?**

Comment: What does verify mean? You just said there is a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription string. That is all you need to know. If I were Apple I would still reject that string as meaningless, but the string exists so there is nothing to test.

Comment: @matt Basically they upload an image, showing an alert that the app needs permissions to use the photos, the alert does not display the content put inside NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription. I would like to test this myself, before submitting again.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload an image"? You do not need any permissions to "upload" something, and if the user's task is to use the built-in picker to choose an image from the photo library, you do not need any permissions for that either. You need to explain to the user (and to Apple) what the _actual_ purpose of the _actual_ permission is for.

Comment: How did you do this using Expo?: After building ios using expo build:ios I was able to verify that that the string existed in the Info.plist file.......I thought Expo hides the ios folder which contains the plist file

Comment: @JoMomma I uploaded it again, no changes, and it was accepted... No idea why and what happened.

Comment: Yeah, I'm dealing with this now.....It seems to be poorly documented. I can't test in Expo either. I may have to upload a new binary and test it in TestFlight but there should certainly be a simpler way

Answer (score 5):

My solution:

First I set up my app for an EAS build. If you're not familiar with that you should check out the docs: https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/

Basically you do this:

1. install eas-cli: `npm install -g eas-cli`
2. run `eas build:configure` to initialize an eas.config file.
3. configure your eas build profiles. Mine look like this:

[image]

I collapsed the submit block to hide my credentials. Sorry for the photo instead of code/text. The formatter kept messing it up.

Any way, trigger a build using `eas build -p ios --profile development`. Notice the simulator flag set to true. This will allow you to run this as a stand-alone binary in your simulator.

When your build completes, go to expo.io and log into your account. Click on your project and download the binary for your ios build (under the builds tab). Unzip the binary and drag it into your simulator. You may be prompted with a message that says that you need to start up your development server. Just follow those simple instructions and there you go. You'll be able to see if your `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` string updated.

Admittedly, this can be a pain in the @ss and you're kind of executing outside of the expo environment, but it solves the problem of wondering if your string has updated before posting to the store again.

Best of luck. Hope that helps.