# expo-image-picker change message for cameraPermission not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to change the message that expo-image-picker defaults to when a user is asked to give permission for the app to use their phone camera. The apple store refused my app saying I needed to be more specific on why I am asking for permission to use the camera. I saw in expo-image-picker documentation that I should be able to do this using the app.json file.  However, it is not working.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Someapp",
    "slug": "Someapp",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/Icon-167.png",
    "scheme": "com.someapp.dev",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/Icon-167.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.someapp.dev",
      "buildNumber": "4"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.someapp.dev",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/Icon-167.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "versionCode": 4
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxx"
      }
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static"
          }
        }
      ],
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "The app accesses your photos to allow you to set a profile picture. This makes it easier for them to identify you. It is only ever used for this single purpose.",
          "cameraPermission": "The app accesses your camera to allow you to set a profile picture. This makes it easier for them to identify you. It is only ever used for this single purpose."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: My project does not have an info.plist.  It seems like when using expo, you are supposded to be able to set the items you would set in info.plist from within the app.json.  But maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: I just created a brand new expo and indeed there's no iOS project. On native projects permissions are not related to plugins but to the native project itself.

Comment: it seems to be related to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70379858/how-to-test-the-purpose-string-of-nsphotolibraryusagedescription-in-ios-using-ex

Comment: what you need is the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription in the final iOS bundle.